# Print Matrix with Arrays.toString

Tags: java, arrays

The following code asks the user the number of words to create:

```
    String sInt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cuántas palabras vamos a capturar?");
    int palabras = Integer.parseInt(sInt);
    char[][] charMatrix = new char[palabras][];
```

The objective is to save the words in a matrix and print it, saving each character in a different matrix dimention.

```
    for (int i = 0; i<palabras; i++) {
        String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Palabra: ");
        for(int j = 0; j<=str.length() - 1; j++) {
            charMatrix[i] = new char [str.length()];
            charMatrix[i][j] = str.charAt(j);
        }
    }
```

Lets say the user chose 2 words, and they were hello and bye. The next line prints the matrix.

```
    for(int r = 0; r <charMatrix.length; r++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charMatrix[r]));
    }
```

It should print:

```
    [h,e,l,l,o]
    [b,y,e]
```

But instead prints:

```
    [ , , , ,o]
    [ , ,e]
```

Comment: FYI `j<=str.length() - 1 == j < str.length()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `charMatrix[i] = new char [str.length()];` up, before `for` loop. You need to set that array once after reading `str` from user. Currently at start of each iteration you are storing in `charMatrix[i]` new array which doesn't contain previously set values, so after last iteration you are getting empty array with only last element set (since last iteration was placing only that element).

BTW you can simplify your code and remove inner loop by using `str.toCharArray()` which returns `char[]` array with characters held by `str`.